# ng-disabled is not disabling a button in Angular JS 1.0.6?

Tags: angularjs

I have tire out the following options,

if we use ng-disabled the element will always be enabled when the value are {false, true, disabled, enabled}.

if we use disabled the element will always be disabled when the value is {false, true, disabled, enabled}.

Here is my Sample code please help me to resolve this,

```
<div class="container container-mobile_content ">
    <div class="module module-mobile_content ">
    <form name="initialForm" novalidate>
        <div class="copy">
            <br>

            <p class="module-mobile_content">
                <span translate="label.registration.text.1.1"/>
            </p>
            <br>
            <div class="module-mobile_content" ui-view/>
            <br/>
            <div class="module-form">
                <b><span translate="label.policynumber"></span></b>
                <input type="text" name="policyNumber" ng-model="user.policyNumber" required/>
                <span style="color: #ce0803; font-size:x-small" ng-show="initialForm.policyNumber.$error.required">*required</span>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>

            <button ng-click="validatePolicy()" ng-disabled="initialForm.$invalid">{{ 'message.next' | translate }}{{initialForm.$invalid}}</button>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the source for your translate filter, and also try running this code without the no validate directive, by default the angular validation will appear over the browser's native one, so it's not really necessary, and can actually break things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue has something to do with your translate filter, or\and to the angular version.

Please examine [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkiynGH0VwLeexok0v0L?p=preview), it is your precise code, without the translate filter, and with angular 1.0.8(previous production version, 1.0.6 is deprecated)

Comment: side note: as of [november 8th](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/11/angularjs-120-timely-delivery.html), 1.2.0 is the latest stable version.

Comment: Correct again, my bad

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the reply. But I have deployed the same code in an 2.3.7 X86 Intel version of Android Emulator.Still Its not getting disabled.

Comment: Guys, is it because of the emulator I am getting this issue, as I am not even able to identify whether the button is enabled or disabled in the emulator. Please correct me this is an urgent related task